# what is the purpose of the iif in vb

Tags: vb.net, iif

So, what is the purpose of the iif in vb? I know what it does, but I can't uderstand what is it for?

Update: I know what it does. But "if(,,)" does the same. The only difference is that "Iif" will evaluate both expressions. So what is the purpose of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows for a concise boolean logic expression which produces a value

```
Dim value = Iif(someTest, trueValue, falseValue)
```

Without the `Iif` or `If` operator this has to be expanded into a more combursome set of statements

```
Dim value;
If someTest Then
  value = trueValue
Else
  value = falseValue
End If
```

Comment: Yes. I know that. But why we need "Iif" if we have "IF"?

Comment: Are you talkiing about the ternary style `If`?  If so there is no need for `Iif` now with the `If` operator being around.  `If` was introduced in VB.Net 10 so `Iif` needs to be around for legacy reasons, nothing else.

Comment: Yes. I asked about this. Thank you.

Comment: Other than being short, aren't both iif() and if() slow.  It seems that this was discussed somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, IIF(a, b, c) returns b if a is true, or c if a is false.

Comment: Yes. It will evaluate b and c expressions and will return one of them when "If(a,b,c)" will evaluate only b OR c. So when we need "Iif"?

Comment: You don't need IIF. You can just use a regular if...else statement. But IIF provides a nice, compact, shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `Iif` in new VB.NET code, but has been kept for backward compatibility with existing code.

If you *do* ever still want `Iif`, code it yourself as `Iif(Of T)` at least, so you can avoid the casting that is otherwise required when you have `Option Strict On`.