# Visual Studio 2005 - is nothing check

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

Can you please tell me why this line of code gives error:- "Object reference not set to instance of an object"

```
 searchstr = IIf(
    Not searchstr Is Nothing
    AndAlso searchstr.Length > 0,
    searchstr.Replace("Desig_id", "designation_id"), "")
```

Also can you provide alternative to make this type of validation?

Comment: I think because the searchstr is null or nothing and you are trying to check its length and do replaces inside it

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478/if-iif-and-if. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431326/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-iif-in-vb. Etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using VB.NET IIF I get NullReferenceException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428959/using-vb-net-iif-i-get-nullreferenceexception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IIf` function isn't behaving how you think it does. It's *not* a ternary-style operator a la C++ or C#. It's just a normal function, which means both your conditional check *and* the searchstr.Replace are being evaluated before passing it to `IIf`. If searchstr is null, searchstr.Replace(...) is going to throw a NullReferenceException, even though you expected it wouldn't be called at all.

The If operator was added in VS2008 to support this, but if you're in 2005, you have to expand it to an If/Else block:

```
If Not searchstr Is Nothing AndAlso searchstr.Length > 0 Then
    searchstr = searchstr.Replace("Desig_id", "designation_id")
Else
    searchstr = ""
End If
```

Comment: More precisely: it not depends on Visual Studio version, its about .NET Framework version. You are probably using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Well explained, sir. Ever since learning this very thing, I have changed any `IIf()` I come across (in a .NET 3.5 or higher project) to `If()`, since that is almost always preferable.

Comment: @Kamil: good catch, but it's more subtle than that! Since this particular feature needs no CLR support nor any class library support, it only depends on you having a compiler that's compiling language version VB9 or later. Using VS2010 right now, I can use the If operator in a project targeting .NET 2.0. :-)

Comment: @Kamil: thanks for bringing that up. You had me running to the compiler as soon as you I saw your comment...

Answer (score 1):

iif is a function, not an operator like the c# ?
that means there is no expression short circuiting.
Also, your code should look like:

```
searchstr = IIf(
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstr),
    searchstr.Replace("Desig_id", "designation_id"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability you might be better writing it as

```
If string.isnullorempty(searchstr) Then
  searchstr.Replace("Desig_id","designation_id")
else
  searchstr = string.empty
End if
```

The isnullorempty checks both the length and whether the string is initialised.